# Why do I need git add when I use git commit -a

Tags: git, commit

I have learned, that `git commit -a` includes `git add`. But still I need to do `git add .` all the time when there are new files because `git commit -a` wont track them.

Comment: commit will only work on files in INDEX, it will not add new files to INDEX. Also note, shotgun methods like `git commit -a` or `git add .` can cause unintended consequences if your working directory is not in the state you think it is. for instance, create a new file in the WD, without adding it to INDEX. then checkout a different branch. even though you are now on a different branch, the untracked file is still in the WD, so if you run `git add ,`, it will be unintentionally added to INDEX, and made part of the repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--all` option is *not* equivalent to `git add <REPOSITORY_ROOT>`. As per [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit):

> -a
> --all
>
> > Tell the command to automatically stage files that have been modified and deleted, but **new files you have not told Git about are not affected.**

(emphasis mine)

`git add`, on the other hand, also adds untracked (“new”) files.